# Is it possible to embed TCL directly into a Cisco startup-config?

Tags: cisco, ios, startup-scripts, tcl

Is it possible to embed TCL directly into a Cisco startup-config? From the (lack of) information I'm finding, it doesn't look do-able.

I have a tool that generates Cisco configurations based on some simple criteria. I'd like to include in this script a version check that will fail if the installed version of IOS is less than the minimum required.

I guess the "real" question is: Is it possible to construct a startup-config that completely fails to load if the IOS version fails the check?

I'd still like to know about TCL in general. I know a separate file can be prepared and parsed, but I'd like to have it all in a single startup-config configuration script.

Comment: So you want to set all configuration to default if the version doesn't match a specific IOS?

Comment: @resmon6 Not exactly. I just want the config file to fail if the version isn't as expected. So whatever defaults are on the device would still hold, I guess.

Comment: You can do this with Embedded Event Manager. Take a look at [this](http://blog.ioshints.info/2008/09/send-e-mail-after-router-reload.html). I just had some work come up but I'll see if I can whip something up soon.

Comment: what IOS version are you running?

Comment: @resmon6 15.1 is the target version. I'd like the startup-script to fail spectacularly on 15.0. The reason is because 15.1 is required for certain security commands to work, but our techs don't notice when those commands fail, and the service otherwise "works". Thanks!

Comment: @resmon6 Thanks for the EEM direction! I'm wading through the docs now and can think of a few ways to use this. Probably will register an applet to check the IOS version and delete sensitive config lines if the version check fails. Thanks again.